# PHPMailer sending an email that contains a form

Tags: php, forms, email, phpmailer

I have PHPMailer sending an HTML email to myself - background-color works.
But I've not been able to insert a form into that email.
It might be that Microsoft doesn't allow it.
But I can't see previous posts on the matter.

Sending an email with the following content...

```
<html>
   <body style='background-color:#ffff00'>
      Test form 1
      <form method='post' id='form-assess' name='form-assess'
            action='https://www.demowebsitetestplace.com/form.php'>
         Name
         <input type='text' />
         <input type='submit'>
      </form> />
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at [this blog post](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/).

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? I don't see where it sends any email

Comment: Could You provide a raw mail content You have received? The source code of the e-mail? The mail clients do funny things with HTML content.